# Eclipse : To activate this refactoring, please select a set of compilation units, packages, source folders or Java projects"

Tags: eclipse

I have this error en Eclipse :

### To activate this refactoring, please select a set of compilation units, packages, source folders or Java projects

I couldn't find how to fix it, I tried to remove completely eclipse but even after re-install I have this error.

Does anyone have an idea?

The only thing that I could find is : "I fixed it.I changed the build's source code locations " but I don't know how to do that.

EDIT---

I have this error when I tried to fix the warning by clicking on : "Infer Generic Type Arguments.."

Comment: The project relevant metadata are stored in workspace directory.If you want to have something like reset, then try creating a new workspace and import project/source files to it.

Comment: I would suggest you avoid Eclipse's *Infer Generic Type Arguments* and do a little bit of research on generics. You may have some flaws in your code, or the warnings just scare you.

Comment: I finally change the location of the workspace directory as LeNoob suggest and also fix the warning issue by adding some code without using "Eclipse's Infer Generic Type Arguments" as GGrec said.

Comment: I can't get this fixed. I removed the project from the workspace (which is now completely empty), imported it, and the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told Eclipse enough about your sources for it to do a correct refactoring.  As it mentions, it needs a Java project (a specific term in Eclipse for a project it creates, not just a collection of folders somewhere on your hard drive).

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_project